# Mesclar dois arrays que tenham espaços em branco

Tags: javascript, array

Eu tenho dois arrays:

```
const array1 = ['lorem','ipsum','teste','','hello','','vol']
const array2 = ['lorem','ipsum','teste','array2Tes','','world','vol']
```

Como faço para mesclar as partes vazias do primeiro array com as preenchidas do segunda array na mesma posição. Na posição 3 do **array1** está vazia , mas nessa mesma posição do **array2** está preenchido com **'array2Tes'**. E, na posição 4 do **array2** está vazia, mas nessa mesma posição no array1 está preenchida com **'hello'**.
Ficaria assim:

```
const newArray = ['lorem','ipsum','teste','array2Tes','hello','world','vol']
```

Como faço para fazer essa mesclagem?

Comment: As duas arrays terão sempre o mesmo tamanho?

Comment: Isso. Sempre terão o msm tamanho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Se atente ao tamanho das arrays, o exemplo é com base nas Arrays informadas.***

```
const array1 = ['lorem','ipsum','teste','','hello','','vol']
const array2 = ['lorem','ipsum','teste','array2Tes','','world','vol']

array1.forEach((elemento, index ) => {
    elemento === '' ? array1[index] = array2[index] : '';   
})

console.log(array1)
```

Comment: Os arrays serão maiores que esse exemplo que passei, mas sempre serão do mesmo tamanho. Acho que sua resposta supri a necessidade. VLWSS

Comment: Sim, o tamanho é importante, Mas dentro do `forEach` vc pode fazer mais validações.

Comment: Detalhe: dentro do `forEach` você já possui o elemento de `array1` em `elemento`, você pode economizar algumas operações retornando o valor dele ao invés de buscá-lo novamente com `array1[index]`.

Comment: Utilizar o elemento não é possível, porém, é possível enviado ao callback o array em questão. Exemplo: `array1.forEach((elemento, index, theArray) => {
 elemento === '' ? theArray[index] = array2[index] : ''; 
})`

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma é usando `.map()` criando uma nova array:

```js
const array1 = ['lorem','ipsum','teste','','hello','','vol']
const array2 = ['lorem','ipsum','teste','array2Tes','','world','vol']

const newArray = array1.map( (e,i) => { return !e ? array2[i] : array1[i] } );

console.log(newArray);
```